# Naming the Folder with username/unique long string

Tags: php, directory

i need to create a separate folder for each user on the server to store specific images.Is it better to use the username as the foldername or `md5(uniqid($dealername,true));`

the string generated is unique but long.Will need to store this string in database and pass it to android app during web service call.

Comment: Well if you make sure that every username has to be unique I guess you can use the username

Comment: @Rizier123 its not a username..  actually its the name of the dealer.. i think i will go with the dealername as there wont be 2 dealers with the same name or will there be?

Comment: Or you could do just a number which you count up e.g. `dealer-00001`, `dealer-00002` and so on

Comment: @Rizier123 Tried auto incrementing db,but there are times when incrementing error occurs.which will put the whole system down.

Comment: @Rizier123 Anyway i should check for duplicate dealer names.. so will go with the dealer name only

Answer (score 0):

You can try setting the user_id (primary key) of the user table as the folder name so that it will be unique.